# ssh-keyscan returns empty output, when executed several times

Tags: ssh

I played around with ssh and found an interesting (maybe intended) behavior.
I have 3 hosts: Machine A, B and C. I am using ssh to access C from A or B.

1. ssh from A to C - works
2. ssh from B to C - works
3. On A: Execute ssh-keyscan -Ht rsa C_ip_address couple of times (4) serially, returns me the public key correctly. But when I execute it for the next time, it returns empty output and I cannot ssh to C from A anymore, get only connection timed out as a response.
4. On B: I can still ssh to C. But when I do the same as in step 3, I am not able to ssh to C anymore.

Telnet returns time out as well.

If I want to ssh to C from A or B again, I have to restart C (C will change the IP address).
Does this mean that, C puts A and B on some blacklist, because of some suspicion of a malicious intent ?
Note: I did the serial execution of ssh-keyscan in ca 3 minutes.

Comment: This looks like the type of behaviour `fail2ban` and similar products will do; 4 failed login attempts from an IP causes it to be banned for a while.  You might see it in `iptables -L` output.

Comment: @StephenHarris You are right, there is an 
`Chain sshguard (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  51.28.205.35.bc.googleusercontent.com  anywhere   
entry in the iptables`. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my question:

@Stephen Harris was right, that the cause for this was a `fail2ban` behaviour. 
Because the `iptables -L` returned `Chain sshguard (1 references) target prot opt source destination DROP all -- 51.28.205.35.bc.googleusercontent.com anywhere entry in the iptables` entry.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to allow for more `ssh-keyscan` without banning? This seems like a somewhat harmless command, especially being idempotent—it's not like the key changes between calls so the caller has no benefit to "getting the key again"...